# org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query again

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am new in Spring and Hibernate. I am trying to insert and retrieve all data from database. I have inserted data in mySql db and now i am trying to retrieve all data from database but i am getting some exception. What i can do to fix the problem.

```
Jul 04, 2012 10:46:58 AM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
WARNING: SQL Error: 1064, SQLState: 42000
Jul 04, 2012 10:46:58 AM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
SEVERE: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to     your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') as emp1_0_, employee0_.address as address0_, employee0_.emp_email as emp3_0_, ' at line 1
Hibernate: select employee0_.emp_id) as emp1_0_, employee0_.address as address0_, employee0_.emp_email as emp3_0_, employee0_.manager_id as manager4_0_, employee0_.emp_name as emp5_0_ from employee employee0_
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
```

Hibernate code is

```
public void getAll() {

    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = null;
    try {
        transaction = (Transaction) session.beginTransaction();
        List employees = session.createQuery("from Employee").list();
        for (Iterator iterator = employees.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            Employee employee = (Employee) iterator.next();
            System.out.println(employee.getName());
        }
        transaction.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        transaction.rollback();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Employee.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employee")
public class Employee {

private int id;
private String name;
private String email;
private String address;
private int managerId;


@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="emp_id)")
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name="emp_name")
public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

@Column(name="emp_email")
public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

@Column(name="address")
public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

@Column(name="manager_id")
public int getManagerId() {
    return managerId;
}

public void setManagerId(int managerId) {
    this.managerId = managerId;
}
}
```

Comment: can you please paste your Employee.java class as well

Comment: Employee.java is added bellow.

Comment: You should vote up if your problem is resolved

Answer (score 6, accepted):

this

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="emp_id)")
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

should be - 

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="emp_id")
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
```

Remove `)` from the end of `name="emp_id)"`

Answer (score 3):

There is typo error in the Id field emp_id, having extra ')'

```
@Column(name="emp_id)")
```

Remove the curly bracket it will work.

Answer (score 2):

column name for id you specified is containing ) remove it e.g.

replace 
`@Column(name="emp_id)") with @Column(name="emp_id")`

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name="emp_id")
```